# Проблема с подключением локальной зависимости Maven

Tags: java, maven

Здравствуйте у меня есть Maven проект:

```
// Родительский pom file

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ru.servers</groupId>
<artifactId>serverside</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<modules>
    <module>gameserver</module>
    ...
    <module>protocol</module>
</modules>

<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>serverside</name>
<description>Server side for game</description>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.servers</groupId>
            <artifactId>protocol</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/protocol/target/protocol-0.1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        ...           

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Также есть библиотека, у нее нет Main функции, просто набор классов:

```
// pow file библиотеки

<parent>
    <artifactId>serverside</artifactId>
    <groupId>ru.servers</groupId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>protocol</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<properties>
    <project.java.version>1.8</project.java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project.java.version}</source>
                <target>${project.java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    ...

</dependencies>
```

И есть сервер, которые должен подключить своб собственную библиотеку:

```
// pom file игрового сервера

<parent>
    <artifactId>serverside</artifactId>
    <groupId>ru.servers</groupId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>gameserver</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<properties>
    <project.java.version>1.8</project.java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project.java.version}</source>
                <target>${project.java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>GameServer</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ru.servers.gameserver.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.servers</groupId>
        <artifactId>protocol</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    ...        

</dependencies>
```

Но когда я пытаюсь скомпилировать сервер при помощи maven, то у меня появляется следующая ошибка(библиотека компилируется и собирается нормально):

```
Failed to execute goal on project gameserver: Could not resolve dependencies for project ru.servers:gameserver:jar:0.1.0: Could not find artifact ru.servers:protocol:jar:0.1.0 at specified path C:\Users\User\Desktop\RacingWorld\ServerSide\gameserver\protocol\target\protocol-0.1.0.jar -> [Help 1]
```

Пишет, что не может найти этот jar файл, хотя он находится в этой папке, может кто-нибудь подскажет в чем проблема, а то уже и не знаю чего делать...

Comment: все просто - это же maven: 1. удалить из родительского pom'a зависимость с артефактом protocol; 2. выполнить mvn install

Comment: Failed to execute goal on project databaseserver: Could not resolve dependencies for project ru.servers:databaseserver:jar:0.1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at ru.servers:protocol:jar:0.1.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ru.servers:protocol:jar:0.1.0: Could not find artifact ru.servers:serverside:pom:0.1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Сделал, как вы сказали

Comment: тут не совсем понятно, databaseserver это видимо еще один из модулей описанных в родительском pom файле, и он имеет в зависимостях модуль/артефакт protocol, если все корректно прописано в pom файле databaseserver  модуля, то может быть, что декларация модуля databaseserver  идет раньше декларации модуля protocol в секции modules родительского pom файла, поэтому databaseserver  не может собраться без собранного protocol